# Get Mbase (MVA) of Machine from PSSE for Python code

Tags: python-2.7, psse

Please help me to get Mbase (MVA) of Machine from PSSE for Python.

I would like to use this to calculate with inertia (H) value.

Although I can get H as syntax below, I don't know how to get Mbase (MVA).

> ```
> ierr = psspy.rwdy(option1=2,option2=0,out=0,ofile="C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\EXAMPLE\python_test1.out")
>
> 21421 'GENROU' 1 11.000 0.47000E-01 0.67000 0.50000E-01 6.2300 0.0000 2.1000 1.5500 0.21000 0.40000 0.16000 0.13000 0.36100 0.69300
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `psspy.macdat()` as follows to store the value in a new variable `mbase`:

```
ierr, mbase = psspy.macdat(
    ibus=bus_number,  # bus number where machine is connected as an `int` object
    id=id_,           # machine ID as a `str` object
    string='MBASE',  
)
```

You will of course need to have already defined `bus_number` and `id_`.

You may see the other options by reading the docstring:

```
import psse34
import psspy

help(psspy.macdat)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support.

Based on your introduction, I can get Mbase.

Due to a lot of machines, so I have to use `for loop` in order to get all of the power data of machines. Please give me some advice whether there is any other way than to use a `for loop`.

Please see the picture result on Notepad++
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykNLr.jpg)

That's so kind of you.

```
import psse34
import psspy

# Last case:
CASE = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\EXAMPLE\savnw.sav"
psspy.psseinit(12000)
psspy.case(CASE)

ierr = psspy.dyre_add(dyrefile="C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\EXAMPLE\savnw.dyr")
ierr = psspy.rstr("C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\EXAMPLE\savnw.snp")
ierr = psspy.rwdy(1,1,ofile="C:\Program Files (x86)\PTI\PSSE34\EXAMPLE\python_test1.out") # find inertia (H) of machine
machine1=[101,102,206,211,3011,3018]
for x in machine1:
    ierr, mbase = psspy.macdat(ibus=x, id='1', string='MBASE') # find power of machine
    print(mbase)
```

Comment: Please post this as a new question.